# Convexity of $g(x) = f(x) + M x^2$

Tags: continuity, convex-analysis

> Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with class $C^2$. Prove there exists $M \ge 0$ such that $g(x) = f(x) + M x^2$, where $x \in [a,b]$, is convex.

I get that $g''(x) = f''(x) + 2M$ to show that $g$ is convex I need to show that $g''(x) \ge 0$, as $M \ge 0$ I just need to prove that $f''(x) \ge 0$, but how do I get that?

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $f''\geq 0$. However can you show that $f''$ is bounded?

Comment: $f$ is of class $C^2$ so it has a continuous second derivative, i.e. $f''$ has an infimum as we are working on $[a,b]$. You can pick $M$ such that $g''(x)\geq 0$ then (based on $\inf f''$).

Comment: Sorry! I unintentionally click to post without reviewing.

Comment: I'm practicing English and my math expression formatting too, so take it easy.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst How $M$ can guarantee that $g''(x) \ge 0$

Comment: $g''(x) \geq \inf f''(x) +2M$, so choose $M> |- \inf f''(x)| \geq 0$ and you are onto a winner

Comment: cool! But, why $M > |- inf f''(x)|$

Comment: i can't see why $inf f''(x)$ can't be bigger than $M$

Comment: you are allowed to choose what $M$ is, so just choose it as $|-\inf f''(x)|+1$